# Why does Groovy not execute a class in a program if there is a line of code outside the class?

Tags: groovy

Groovy Version: 2.4.5 JVM: 1.8.0_151 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux

I have tried two versions of my Groovy program.   The class "Example" runs if I have nothing else in the program (e.g., no 'println "Test"').

Why does the Example class not run if I have a "println" statement?

```
class Example {
   static void main(String[] args) {
      def clos = {println "Hello World"};
      clos.call();
   }
}

println "Test"
```

I expect the above program to print this when it is run:

> Hello World
>
> Test

Why does the class not execute when there is another line outside of it?

Answer (score 9):

You need to be aware of a few things. When you create a script (let's call it `someScript.groovy`) with the following content:

```
#!groovy

println "Test"

println 21 + 21
```

it gets compiled to the following class:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.Script;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper;

public class someScript extends Script {
    public someScript() {
    }

    public someScript(Binding context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        InvokerHelper.runScript(someScript.class, args);
    }

    public Object run() {
        ((someScript)this).println("Test");
        Object var10000 = null;
        ((someScript)this).println(21 + 21);
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the body of the Groovy script is represented as a method `run()` in the generated class. When we add a class to this script, let's say the `Example` class from your question, the body of `run()` method does not change at all - the class gets compiled to an `Example.class` bytecode file and that's it:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

import groovy.lang.Closure;
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GeneratedClosure;

public class Example implements GroovyObject {
    public Example() {
        MetaClass var1 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var1;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        class _main_closure1 extends Closure implements GeneratedClosure {
            public _main_closure1(Object _outerInstance, Object _thisObject) {
                super(_outerInstance, _thisObject);
            }

            public Object doCall(Object it) {
                DefaultGroovyMethods.println(Example.class, "Hello World");
                return null;
            }

            public Object call(Object args) {
                return this.doCall(args);
            }

            public Object call() {
                return this.doCall((Object)null);
            }

            public Object doCall() {
                return this.doCall((Object)null);
            }
        }

        Closure clos = new _main_closure1(Example.class, Example.class);
        clos.call();
    }
}
```

When we run Groovy compiler to compile `someScript.groovy` (`groovyc someScript.groovy`) and we list generated classes we will see something like this:

```
ls -lh *.class
-rw-rw-r--. 1 wololock wololock 2,0K 12-07 10:26  Example.class
-rw-rw-r--. 1 wololock wololock 1,6K 12-07 10:26 'Example$_main_closure1.class'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 wololock wololock 1,4K 12-07 10:26  someScript.class
```

> **NOTE**: this `Example$_main_closure1.class` represents a closure used in `Example.main()` method

Now, let's see what happens if we comment (or remove) `println` statements from the `someScript.groovy` file and we compile it:

*someScript.groovy*

```
#!groovy

class Example {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        def clos = {println "Hello World"};
        clos.call();
    }
}

//println "Test"
//
//println 21 + 21
```

Compile time:

```
> groovyc someScript.groovy

> ls -lh *.class
-rw-rw-r--. 1 wololock wololock 2,0K 12-07 10:31  Example.class
-rw-rw-r--. 1 wololock wololock 1,6K 12-07 10:31 'Example$_main_closure1.class'
```

As you can see, there is no `someScript.class` class file generated. It happens because the script file we just compiled does not contain any body, but it has the `Example` class inside. When you run such script Groovy tries to locate the first static `main()` method to execute it - that is why running the following script produces `Hello World` output:

```
> groovy someScript.groovy 
Hello World
```

Let's go further and add another class on top of the `someScript.groovy` file:

*someScript.groovy*

```
#!groovy 

class Foo {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        println "Bar"
    }
}


class Example {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        def clos = {println "Hello World"};
        clos.call();
    }
}

//println "Test"
//
//println 21 + 21
```

The body of the script is still commented out. Let's compile and see what class files get generated:

```
> groovyc someScript.groovy

> ls -lh *.class
-rw-rw-r--. 1 wololock wololock 2,0K 12-07 10:35  Example.class
-rw-rw-r--. 1 wololock wololock 1,6K 12-07 10:35 'Example$_main_closure1.class'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 wololock wololock 1,8K 12-07 10:35  Foo.class
```

We can see 3 class files, just as expected. Let's see what happens if we run the script with `groovy` command:

```
> groovy someScript.groovy                             
Bar
```

Now as you can see the `Foo.main()` method got executed because Groovy located this method on top of the script file and it assumed that this is the main method we want to run.

Let's finalize this with the example containing two classes and script body:

*someScript.groovy*

```
#!groovy

class Foo {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        println "Bar"
    }
}


class Example {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        def clos = {println "Hello World"};
        clos.call();
    }
}

println "Test"

println 21 + 21
```

Compile time:

```
> groovyc someScript.groovy

> ls -lh *.class
-rw-rw-r--. 1 wololock wololock 2,0K 12-07 10:39  Example.class
-rw-rw-r--. 1 wololock wololock 1,6K 12-07 10:39 'Example$_main_closure1.class'
-rw-rw-r--. 1 wololock wololock 1,8K 12-07 10:39  Foo.class
-rw-rw-r--. 1 wololock wololock 1,4K 12-07 10:39  someScript.class
```

This time a class `someScript` got generated because the script body is not empty. Last look at the generated `someScript.class` file:

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

import groovy.lang.Binding;
import groovy.lang.Script;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper;

public class someScript extends Script {
    public someScript() {
    }

    public someScript(Binding context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        InvokerHelper.runScript(someScript.class, args);
    }

    public Object run() {
        ((someScript)this).println("Test");
        Object var10000 = null;
        ((someScript)this).println(21 + 21);
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see it didn't change compared to our first example (when there were no classes inside the script, but only two println statements), so we can't expect anything else than running `someScript.run()` method to happen. Let's run the script:

```
> groovy someScript.groovy
Test
42
```

### Conclusion

- When you create a Groovy script its body gets moved and compiled as `scriptName.run()` method, and it gets executed.
- If you add a class with a `main()` method to a Groovy script and you keep script body, added class `main()` method won't get executed - it only compiles the class, and you can use it explicitly in your script body if needed.
- If you add a class with a `main()` method to a Groovy script and you don't put any script body (any statements/expressions outside the class) then Groovy searches for the first static `main()` method, and it executes it.